# Is it possible to remove shapes from a physics body in Cannon.js?

Tags: aframe

I am looking to dynamically update the shape of a physics body with Cannon.js in the context of A-Frame and aframe-physics-system. There is `body.addShape`, but no `body.removeShape` equivalent.

Would we have to recreate the physics body from scratch and repopulate the shapes? Or would clearing the `shapes` array manually work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just modify or replace the shapes array of the body.

`el.components['dynamic-body'].body.shapes = []`

Comment: Not sure but you may also need to call [`body.updateMassProperties()`](http://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/docs/classes/Body.html#method_updateMassProperties.)